# D3.js reference error in Jupyter Notebook from local copy

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, reference, jupyter-notebook

I have only gotten D3.js to load in a Jupyter Notebook once.  That was when the path for my folder was `"/lib/d3/d3.js"`.  However, I downloaded both D3 v3.5 and v4.4, so I created different folders for both versions in my lib folder.
Ever since then, I haven't been able to get D3 to load in the notebook, and I have no idea why.  I have even tried to load with CDN hosted versions, and have been unsuccessful.  Is D3 picky about specifically having the `"lib/d3/d3.js"` path?  This is what I've been doing:

1. Verify the path to the correct D3 file for the version I want to use
   ('python_data_analysis' is the root folder[folder structure
   image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNYWR.jpg)
2. Load D3 into my Jupyter notebook (note: no errors on
   load)[referencing the path from step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i4FK.jpg)
3. Run my D3 code only to have Jupyter Notebook barf on the fact that
   it doesn't know what d3 is:

   "Javascript error adding output!
       ReferenceError: d3 is not defined See your browser Javascript
       console for more details."
4. Javascript console reveals that d3 is undefined.

What gives?  At this point, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  It worked before, and the only thing different is the path.  Are there some security settings at play that I'm not familiar with?  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!